# What AWS role permissions to I need for AWS Cloud Debugging with WebStorm plugin?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm working on a Node app that has been uploaded as a Docker image to ECR and which runs as part of an ECS cluster and which connects to DynamoDB.

We can't debug the app locally -- we haven't been able to get the connection from Loopback to DynamoDB Local to work, but that's another story -- and so I thought perhaps I could use Cloud Debugging. I don't know much about Cloud Debugging, but I wanted to try it out to see if it would help with our use case.

I installed the AWS Toolkit for WebStorm (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11349-aws-toolkit/) and have tried to start using Cloud Debugging. I have up-to-date credentials (shared credentials stored in `~/.aws/credentials`), but it appears my role doesn't have the correct permissions. (see image)

[image]

Our AWS administrator wants to know exactly what permissions I need.  The only information I could find was here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/key-tasks.html#key-tasks-install, but our administrator said that that asks for me to have administrator permissions, which he won't give me.

Comment: For ref purposes (same in other places): 1) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006877379 2) https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/1461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this answer earlier today: it would seem that the help link in the plugin points to the wrong page.  The correct one, with the correct information, is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/ecs-debug.html) .